# change event doesn't fire on ajax loaded forms

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have an HTML document, with the jquery code

```
    $(function(){
[...]
     $("#newNotice").click(function(){
        $("#properties").load("testDiagramm.html #NoticeForm");
        return false;
       });
     function showFormValues(){
        var s = $("form").serialize();
        [... Do things ...]
     }
     $("input, textarea").change(showFormValues);
    });
```

At the beginning there is no form in the HTML document. But i load diffrent forms into the document. One of those request you can see here

```
$("#properties").load("testDiagramm.html #NoticeForm");
```

The problem is. that the codeline

```
$("input, textarea").change(showFormValues);
```

only fire, when the form was loaded at the beginning. What must I do, if i want to execute the function showFormValues(), when I changed something in the formular, which i load later?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Lara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form loses its binding to the DOM after it is reloaded via ajax, so event handlers previously bound to the elements that get injected into the page are lost.

I would normally suggest using event delegation with [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live), but it does not support the change event, so a safe bet would be to rebind using a callback as a second parameter to your $.load function:

```
    $(function(){
[...]
     $("#newNotice").click(function(){
        $("#properties").load("testDiagramm.html #NoticeForm", function() {
            $("input, textarea").change(showFormValues);
        });
        return false;
       });
     function showFormValues(){
        var s = $("form").serialize();
        [... Do things ...]
     }
     $("input, textarea").change(showFormValues);
    });
```